# How can I set up google credential securely with base64 python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I am working on the Google speech api,

I am frustrate that I can only setup using

`os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential.json`

My team said that this way it is not secure, so right now I working on sending it with other method and also encode it with base64

But when I try using the

```
def explicit():
    from google.cloud import storage

    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'acn-depth-3be328555b6e.json')

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)
```

It cannot find my credential

Comment: You are specifying the service account JSON key file using a relative path. Is the file in the same directory as the program's current working directory? Normally, you would specify the full path as credentials should not be stored in the same location as the program's source code.

Comment: Tip: If you are running this code on a Google Cloud compute service, look into using the credentials assigned to the service. That way, you do not need to store the credentials on the system or in source code.

Comment: Why are you encoding in b64 your file? In addition, are you running your workload on GCP or elsewhere? In many situation, you can avoid to use a service account key file.